# Check if next or previous html element gained focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

When I press `tab` or `shift + tab` next or previous html element is preselected but you can also change focus to the next element for example by clicking on an input field if it is next element in tab order.

**Question:** How to check if the `element` lost focused in favour of the next or the previous element in the tab order?

```
self.on("focusout", function(e){
   if(nextOrPreviousElementInTabOrderGotFocus){...}
});
```

The `self` is my component an I cannot rely on page implementation.

Disclaimer: This is NOT a question about handling `tab` key.

Comment: What about tracking focus events at the document (I.e. document.addEventListener('focus',function(e){/*some code */}, true);)?

Comment: Does your page specify any `tabindex` properties, or is the tab order just the natural source order?

Comment: @nnnnnn Maybe I should add in the question that this is the component itself needs to know if the next element on the site is selected or no ity cannot depend on a site it is put in. The `self` from the question is the component.

Comment: So you'd need to allow for the next/prev element possibly being inside an iframe? Or your component being in an iframe by itself? That's getting complicated. I can think of ways that might work fairly simply using the `focus` event if there aren't iframes involved.

Comment: @nnnnnn My component is a quite complicated and customizable dropown(yes, you can make dropdown very complicated) and if it looses focus I need to know if the next element is the one which gained it, I need it to handle arrow keys in iOS native keyboard which don't fire ANY keyboard events beside focusout, but I already have multiple use scenarios around loosing focus so I need to be very specific.